# window.location.href não funciona no Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Tenho uma aplicação feita em Cordova que usa window.location.href para transferir dois valores entre páginas. Tudo funciona bem no Android, no iOS e até no IE, mas quando testo directamente no Windows Phone, diz que não encontra a página.

Conseguem-me ajudar? Alguém já teve o mesmo problema?

O meu código está aqui:

```
window.location.href = nome + ".html" + '?sessao=' + encodeURIComponent(sessao) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(telefone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta não será a melhor forma de transpor valores de página para página.
Sugiro que dê uma olha da no html5 especialmente em window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'label')
e depois para pegar o valor faça
window.localStorage.getItem('key')

Comment: Pois, eu sei que não. O problema é que tentei usar o localStorage tal como o sessionStorage e nenhum funciona no Safari, e queria uma opção que funcionasse de igual modo para os três sistemas operativos.